# the technique save data using Protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a question about the technique save data in the result file using Protocol Buffers technology.

For setting values at the fields Protocol Buffers message we use set() functions. And we have "optional" rule for fields.

Question: Will be size of result file changed If we don't set some fields at the message? Will be size of result file less?

Thanks.

Comment: And сorrectly I understand, the encoded file contains information about the type of field, the number of its tag and the bit of the MSB.

Comment: 9h of neither comment nor answer. So it might not only be me who thinks that this question is unclear. Would you like to add some more details, examples, explanations of the terms you used, quotes from code you have tried, descriptions of what does not go as desired, sample input text, desired results.... Or maybe you study the information on [ask] and [mcve]. Or generally take the [tour].